# Partials with Node.js + Express + Hogan.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, viewengine, hogan.js

I'm developing a site with Node.js + Express and using as view engine Hogan.js.

This is my file `app.js`:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The file `/routes/index.js` is:

```
/*
 * GET pages.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render(
    'index',
    {
      title: 'Home Page',
      author: 'Bruce Wayne'
    }
  );
};

exports.about = function(req, res){
  res.render(
    'about',
    {
      title: 'About Page',
      author: 'Bruce Wayne'
    }
  );
};
```

In `/views` folder, there are:

|- `part.hjs`

|- `index.hjs`

|- `cv.hjs`

The file `part.hjs` is:

```
<h3>Hello {{ author }}</h3>
```

The file `index.hjs` is:

```
<h1>Title: {{ title }} </h1>
{{> part }}
Welcome to Gotham City.
```

And the file `about.hjs` is:

```
<h1>Title: {{ title }}</h1>
{{> part }}
I'm not Joker.
```

I've two questions:

1. How can I use properly the partials in my pages? (this code doesn't work)
2. Can I use the same "title" for two or more pages without repeat the values assignment in file `/routes/index.js`?

Best regards, Vi.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. Sheesh. googled around for a bit until i stumbled upon this gem.

Comment: I think Oren's answer is the correct one for this question.

Comment: Which version of express are you running here?

Comment: What is a partial?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found a solution for the first question.

First of all, I removed `hjs`:

```
npm remove hjs
```

Then, I installed the package `hogan-express`:

```
npm install hogan-express
```

Furthermore, I edited `app.js`:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.enable('view cache');

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

And `routes/index.js`:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.locals = {
    title: 'Title',
  };
  return res.render(
    'index',
    {
      partials:
      {
        part: 'part',
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Now, in `/views` there are `index.html`, `part.html`.
The file `part.html` contains:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

The file `index.html` contains:

```
{{> part}}
Hello world!
```

So, It works fine.

Comment: no need remove `hjs`  now, just append `partials:{ var: file_path }`  in `render`

Comment: @user1775888 is correct... at least for express 4+.  I expanded on this in another answer

Answer (score 6):

At least in Express 4+, partials just work out of the box.  You can use express-generator (from npm) with --hogan or -H option.

After doing that, you need to add partials to the render method:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', 
        { 
            title: 'My Site',
            partials: {header: 'header'} 
        });
});
```

Then, in your template use {{ > xxx }}

```
<body>
  {{> header }}
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

  <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
</body>
```

NOTE: this has header.hjs in views

Answer (score 4):

To use partials with express+hogan, just do the following:

```
app.get('/yourRoute', function(req, res){  
   res.render('yourPartial', function(err,html){
       var partialHTML = html;
       res.render('yourMainView', { myPartial: partialHTML }, function(err,html){
          res.send(html);   
       });     
   });
}
```

And now, yourMainView.html:

```
<p>Something Something Something</p>
{{{partialHTML}}}
<p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
```

Notice the triple '{' instead of double as you usually do! That telling hogan (mustache) to parse this as HTML rather then a string!

That's it.

Comment: Do you know how to assign the to a Javascript variable ? something like:

<script>
var html = '{{{partialHTML}}}';
</script>

But with the security of html escape caracters, etc.. ????

Answer (score 3):

As for your partials question, if you use [consolidate.js](http://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/) you can simply do:

```
res.render('index', {
  partials: {
    part  : 'path/to/part'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem. Partial support is difficult to come by in Express 3.

Your best bet is:
https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js
`npm install consolidate`

These patches take different approaches to adding partials for Hogan:

- https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/pull/51
- https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/pull/29

Unfortunately, the engine doesn't have a hook for filesystem based partials natively, so I think people are confused about how and where partials should be implemented. I ended up with LinkedIn's Dust.js implementation, since partial support was already there. Master actually has even better support, plus I submitted a patch yesterday for relative paths.

Josh

Comment: Thank you so much. I could find a solution for partials using hogan-express package. There are differences with consolidate? Which is better?

Comment: Consolidate may have actual support for partials. In the solution you listed below, you have to forward declare all your partials and pass them in in the options hash. Thats somewhat inconvenient, but not unworkable. In other languages you can just say {>partial/} and it will pull in the partial off the filesystem directly.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `mmm` instead of `hjs`.

https://github.com/techhead/mmm

Disclaimer: I wrote the package.

Just replace all occurrences of `hjs` with `mmm` and partials will start working.  There is a lot more information and an example at the link above.

As for your other question, if you want to share properties across multiple views, you have a couple of options.

When you call `res.render(name, options)`, the `options` will actually be merged onto `res.locals` and `app.locals` before being passed to the rendering engine.  Therefore to set an app-wide property, you can simply assign it to `app.locals`.

```
app.locals.title = "Default Title"; // Sets the default title for the application
```

This concept really applies to just about any Express 3 View Engine.

However, for `mmm` specifically, please see the section under Presentation Logic for more ways to bind values to a template or set of templates.

Comment: I'm having similar problems, and I don't want to follow the next solution and explicitly pass a partials variable to my templates. I'm going to try mmm now. Hope this works. I already tried hulk-hogan, only to realise it didn't work with express 3.x

Comment: Bad suggestion. What if the OP has a ton of work done using hjs already. Changing a template engine to solve such a simple problem is massive overkill