# How to include external template files in hogan-express

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

How can I include external template files like "header.html", "sidebar.html" or "footer.html" in layout file named "layout.html". I am using Hogan-express which is based on HOGAN JS.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the section "Partials" of [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html).

You can find a similar answer from question [Partials with Node.js + Express + Hogan.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783615/partials-with-node-js-express-hogan-js)